# Does a Linux block special file have a corresponding character special file

Tags: devices, character-special-files

Simple codger question from the days of UNIX... Does Linux have character special files which correspond directly to a block special file?  Back in my day  each disk in UNIX had both a block special and a character special file. Also, these special files were permanent inodes in the root file system.

I don't see anything like that; most of `/dev` seems to be automatically generated as a virtual file system and I see nothing like `/dev/rsda1` that would correspond to my root file system (vg) `/dev/sda5`. Has Linux eliminated the block/character pairs completely?

Please excuse if this is a dumb question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Linux doesn't have (and AFAIK never had) those block/char pairs.

If you want to do "raw" i/o (bypass the block buffer cache) you should either open the device with [`O_DIRECT`](https://yarchive.net/comp/linux/o_direct.html) or explicitly attach a [raw device](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/raw.8.html) to it.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/473271/5132 .

Comment: thanks to both of you!